# Using Swift Package Manager with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to use the following library in my XCode project

https://github.com/czechboy0/Socks

It says to use the Swift Package Manager to use the library however I am not sure where I am supposed to put this line???

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/czechboy0/Socks.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 10)
```

I am running mac OS 10.12 Sierra with XCode 8 beta.

I believe that the Swift Package Manager is supposed to come with Swift 3 and Swift 3 is supposed to be part of XCode 8 beta however I am at a loss as to how to actually use the package manager in swift. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am rather new to iOS development and this issue is frustrating ...

If you need me to provide any additional info please ask :)

Comment: Seems to me that iOS is currently not supported from the Swift Package Manager. [https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/swift-package-manager-tutorial-59ade1fc708d#.w9enpn32g] But I doesn't found a quote from Apple!?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use the Swift Package Manager with Xcode, assuming you have Xcode 8.0+ installed is to use the following command in the project root directory:

`swift package generate-xcodeproj`

This will create a new Xcode Project with `Sources` and `Dependencies` imported into the project.

Comment: I tried your command, but I receive this error : error:: no Package.swift found

Comment: You have to type `swift package init` first in order to generate the Package.swift file

Comment: Is there any way to only update the Xcode project after adding a new dependency in the Package.swift?

Answer (score 2):

Swift Package Manager is a tool for managing the distribution of Swift code. It’s integrated with the Swift build system to automate the process of downloading, compiling, and linking dependencies. :swift.org says

To use Socks must be added to Package.swift manifest file.

This is how your manifest file should look like

```
import PackageDescription

    let package = Package(
        name: "DeckOfPlayingCards",
        targets: [],
        dependencies: [
            .Package(url: "https://github.com/czechboy0/Socks.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 10)
        ]
    )
```

When `swift build`command runs it will downloads all dependencies like Carthage or Cocoapodes do.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have placed my Package.swift file with the above content in my project folder (same directory as AppDelegate.swift and Main.storyboard. Now I am getting 'no such module 'PackageDescription'. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that's because you added package.swift to your current target. I guess it should not be added to any target